# How to Call contract inside another contarct in solidity version 0.5.2?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

**I'm using solidity version 0.5.2**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract CampaignFactory{
address[] public deployedCampaigns;

function createCampaign(uint minimum) public{
    address newCampaign  = new Campaign(minimum,msg.sender);  //Error 
//here!!!
    deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
} 

function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(address[] memory){
    return deployedCampaigns;
}
}
```

I'm getting the **error while assigning calling the Campaign contract inside CampaignFactory contract**

```
TypeError: Type contract Campaign is not implicitly convertible to expected 
type address.        
address newCampaign  = new Campaign(minimum,msg.sender);
```

I have another contract called Campaign which i want to access inside CampaignFactory.

```
contract Campaign{
//some variable declarations and some codes here......
```

and I have the constructor as below

```
constructor (uint minimum,address creator) public{
    manager=creator;
    minimumContribution=minimum;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just cast it:

```
address newCampaign = address(new Campaign(minimum,msg.sender));
```

Or better yet, stop using `address` and use the more specific type `Campaign`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract CampaignFactory{
    Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    } 

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(Campaign[] memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!. Thank you @smarkx, I will keep in mind the suggestion you gave.

Answer (score 2):

To call an existing contract from another contract ,pass the contract address inside cast

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract D {
    uint x;
    constructor (uint a) public  {
        x = a;
    }
    function getX() public view returns(uint a)
    {
        return x;
    }
}

contract C {
//DAddress : is the exsiting contract instance address after deployment
    function getValue(address DAddress) public view returns(uint a){
        D d =D(DAddress);
        a=d.getX();
    }
}
```